# Iris of my cat's left eye is discoloring on the edge

Tags: cats, health, biology, eye-disease

A few weeks back, I noticed my cat's left eye's iris is discoloring from the corner (brownish red, iris is gold color). She is 8 years old, female. She has no other complaint whatsoever.

I know I should check with professional, which I did. I took her to the vet. The doc checked how the eye reacts to light and movement, and everything seemed fine according to him. He did not do anything further. Somehow, I felt he was not very confident or sure. He told me to wait and see if the condition progresses. It's been a couple of weeks now. I can't really judge if the discoloring is progressing. However, it definitely did not improve.

My questions:
Do you know what this discoloring is?
Should I seek another vet's opinion, or am too paranoid?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The area does probably have more blood vessels than the rest of the iris of the eye, so it is nothing to worry about; it does not look inflamed or anything.

I once had a cat with a birthmark on her iris; it did look like a hole in the iris (it was only a dark area).

The irises of mammals are all different and can be used to identify each individual animal or person, they are not even the same on both sides of the face.

The iris looks well within the normal variations that cats have in their irises, so there is no reason for you to worry about it at all.